# Unix ls command loop performance

Tags: performance, bash, shell, unix

I have this command

`for i in {0..1000}; do ls -Falh /foo/ | grep bar.$i | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 5`

The number `0..1000` is only for testing, but it can go from 0 to 67864 for example... This command is working but obviously it is slow as hell... Is there a better way to perform this action in less time? It takes about 6 seconds to list a 1000 loop
I edit for more information.

What I want is to retrieve for n that command, and insert that line into an array (I'm using java), so each line will have `"foo" => commandoutput"`
It must return is the fifth (5th) column of each file returned... Like for example

```
4,0K
4,0K
933
1,2K
6
2,2K
428
428
428
428
428
428
428
2,2K
6
2,2K
4,0K
4,0K
109K
0
0
```

The problem is not the output, actually I've managed to use `awk '{print $5}'` instead of doing `tr|cut` but the `ls` command is slow because there are tons of loops... So what I want is a faster way to get that fifth (5th) column where `ls -Falh` displays the filesize...

Comment: I vote for an explanation of what you want to achieve, instead of decipher that pipeline.

Comment: Looks like she wants to grep for multiple patterns `bar.{0..791}` in files in `/foo/` and then show the 5th field (fields separated by some number of spaces).

Comment: Do we need to call ls each time? Is sorting important?

Comment: Note: [don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm having a hard time understanding your edit. Could you give an example with some files, their contents and what your output should be?

Comment: The problem is that now I don't have any file created on system (it is automated by some programs), as soon as I get one I'll put the example.

Comment: @Shahbaz I want to parse the output of the whole ls + grep + tr + cut command, because is what I need to put into the array.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the `grep` supposed to do? Also, is that all the loop? There's no `done` so is there something you forgot to copy? Please understand that we don't know your problem here, so what seems obvious to you is unknown to us.

Comment: It seems the loop was required only to select filenames with numeric part of name being in the given range. Am I right?

Comment: To get the file size, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-see-file-size-on-linux-unix/ . I would suggest `du -h file`.

Comment: @user1381537: What's wrong in using `du -h /foo/*` command?

Comment: @anubhava, range selection

Answer (score 2):

```
find /tmp/ -maxdepth 1 -name bar.\* -printf "%f %k\\n" | cut -d . -f 2|sort -n | awk '$1 > 0 && $1 < 791 { print $2 }'
```

Find prints filenames and size is kilobytes, cut removes non-numeric part of filename, sort sorts on numeric part, awk does number analysis and prints the size.

It seems you don't need sorting, so you can just remove sort from the pipe.

Comment: This command, can output file size in MB/GB/TB? Because I'm handling files with +10TB of size too

Comment: Find can't, but awk could process $2 number in any way you like.